# Calling a FoxPro Report from .Net

Tags: .net, foxpro, visual-foxpro

Has anyone out there got experience of calling a Visual FoxPro report from a .net application? They want to both see the report and print it.

I have to migrate a FoxPro application to .Net and the client would like to keep the FoxPro database + reports but place a new .Net front end on it.

They have extensive Fox reports that they would like to keep. Has anyone tried this?

Comment: Does the client want to see it in foxpro UI or just print it using foxpro?

Comment: Is it foxpro for DOS/Windows, VFP? Please tag it appropriately.

Comment: they want to both preview the report and print it

Comment: You might also be interested in
http://guineu.foxpert.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried this personally; however Foxpro for Windows projects (at least since v.7.0) have had the capability to be compiled as COM objects which might be useful in this situation. Also, in version 9.0 they added the report listener capability which allows you to exert a lot more control over reports. Between these two capabilities, you should be able to call the reports from .Net.

[VFP 9.0 Report Listener](http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~ReportListener~VFP)

And as far as accessing fox tables, Microsoft does offer the OLE methods for interacting with them.

[Microsoft OLE control for VFP 9.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=E1A87D8F-2D58-491F-A0FA-95A3289C5FD4&displaylang=en)

Sorry I don't have the answer but hopefully the links will help.